# Multiple QOpenGLWidgets and QOpenGLTextures. How to destroy textures?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I've set `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)` inorder to share my textures across multiple QpenGLWidgets and it works for the most part. However whenever I try to call destroy() on a texture it fails because QOpenGLTexture checks if the contexts match before deleting. Is this intended behavior or a bug? If it's intended can I manage textures with multiple windows? Do I need to store a pointer to every window and trace the texture back to the one I created the texture on, then call makeCurrent()? Surely there must be a better way?